# How can I determine which query is taking the longest time to execute

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, performance, pdo

I have a list of rules and based on those rules I trigger multiple queries,

But it takes a while for one of the queries to run and I am trying to figure out which one is taking too long so I can figure out a solution.

I don't see why it is taking too long (more than 7 seconds)

All of my queries are update, insert, delete, and couple of a small selects

Note: I am passing a jquery post event so I get a time out error currently and thats because execution time of the page is longer that 7 seconds. I can fix it by increasing the time out value. But I want to fix the root of the problem. it should not take that long to execute a simple select, insert, update or remove.

I am using PDO to execute queries and I am using my own class to connect to the tables and execute queries. if you like to see my class please follow this this [How can I return LastInsertID from PDO whin a method of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753753/how-can-i-return-lastinsertid-from-pdo-whin-a-method-of-a-class)

Comment: on chrome, you can use pagespeed to see how the individual calls are doing, even the network tab should give you perspective

Comment: why can't you add 2 microtime() calls to your class' method to run queries?

Comment: How can I get the microtime() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the PDO class and log the execution time in the query() method. What about something like this:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {

    // extended query method that logs the time a query takes to execute
    public function query($sql) { 
        $start = microtime(true);
        parent::query($sql);

        printf("the query %s took: %s seconds\n",
            $sql,
            microtime(true) - $start);
    }
}
```

Use the class by replacing `PDO` with `MyPDO`. Like this:

*old code*:

```
$connection = new PDO(...);
```

*new code*:

```
$connection = new MyPDO(...);
```

Comment: please, no printfs. why not to make a little usable? add it to array, along with query, and make it print only on demand

Comment: How can I use this method? do I call it every time I run a query?

Comment: @Mike replace PDO by MyPDO in your code and use it like before (with no changes). Note that is is useful in many cases to use a custom class that extends PDO. Not at last for debugging like this

Comment: @hek2mgl, I think what "YourCommonSense" meant is to give me a better usage for what you have wrote. He helped me building my class and he know that I my skills are limited so we took your function and added to make it more useful so I can use it many time to come :)

Comment: Ok, I understood this but I think we should take one step after the another. Will give better usage example later, ok? Do you know how to use the MyPDO class now? Will help otherwise

Comment: @hek2mgl I have replaced PDO with MyPDO so in my class i have this now $this->pdo = new MyPDO($this->connString, $this->userName, $this->passCode, $this->pdo_opt);   but I don't see any output on the page.

Comment: This is ok. Are you using the `$this->pdo->query()` or `$this->pdo->prepare()` ? Can you share the code at pastebin?

Comment: Than you should add the microtime() and printf() :) code to the processQuery() method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27422/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-mike)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the MySQL Slow Query Log to see which DB queries are taking a long time

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

By default it will show queries that take longer than 10 seconds

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time

I would suggest changing that parameter to 2 seconds.

Comment: 2 seconds is based on your project. There are places where I consider 1 minute as fast

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer from hek2mgl but I'm including an explanation.

When I want to know how long anything takes (queries, functions, whatever) the most straightforward way is to take a timestamp just before you start, and then another one as soon as you're done. Subtract the start time from the end time and you know exactly how many seconds has passed.

```
$start = time();
doStuff();
$end = time();
$duration_in_seconds = $end - $start;
echo "Function doStuff() took $duration_in_seconds seconds";
```

You can echo the duration to the screen or log it to a file, whatever is convenient.

If you need to be more precise you can use microtime() as hek2mgl has done.